# R How do I create a dataframe containing a column of lists?

Tags: r

This is my current work around:

```
> df=data.frame(a=1)
> df$b = list(list(2,'a'))
> df
  a    b
1 1 2, a
```

It works, and I don't really mind that `df=data.frame(a=1,b=list(list(1,'a')))` doesn't work .

But referencing `b` requires `[[]]` notation, like this: `df$b[[1]]`.

I'm looking for a solution that would allow simply `df$b`.

Comment: How about this: `df=data.frame(a=1,b=I(list(list(1,'a'))))`

Comment: Why don't you use lists then? The data.frame is for tabular data, your data is clearly not tabular.

Comment: @Stat - nice, but I really don't mind adding the column of lists latter.  What I would like to avoid is having to use the `[[]]` notation.

Comment: @mpiktas - the example is the minimal example to reproduce the issue.

Comment: `df$b` works for me in R 2.15.0

Comment: I voted to close because this isn't a statistical question.  But the answer would be "you can't".  An R dataframe is by definition a list of vectors of equal length; if you want one of those columns to be anything other than a vector of that length, it's no longer a data frame.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is not possible. If you use lists, you will need to use the `[[]]` notation. Otherwise, you can transform the elements of `df$b` using the command `unlist()`.

```
> df$b
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 2

[[1]][[2]]
[1] "a" 

> unlist(df$b)
[1] "2" "a"
> unlist(df$b)[1]
[1] "2"
> unlist(df$b)[2]
[1] "a"
```